# How to use android for SMS Sending app in C#?

Tags: c#, android, gsm, modem, sms-gateway

I am trying to develop a C# application that will be able to send SMS only through GSM Modem. When we connect a GSM Modem to our laptop/PC then we have to check the Port of that modem from Device manager > Modem > Port. But in this case, I want to connect my android phone as a GSM Modem with my laptop and trying to use the port number of my connected mobile phone but it is not connecting as a modem. Please help me if you have any idea or any possibility to connect the android phone as a GSM Modem to laptop. Here is my mode.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TextmagicRest;
using TextmagicRest.Model;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace SMS_Sending_App_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
                sp.PortName = textBox3.Text;
                sp.Open();

                sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sp.WriteLine("AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"" + Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                sp.Write(new byte[] { 26 }, 0, 1);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                var response = sp.ReadExisting();

                if (response.Contains("ERROR"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("SMS failed!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

                else
                    MessageBox.Show("SMS Sent!!!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                sp.Close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }



        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And the important thing is that, when someone send the SMS through this app, the cost will be detecting from the mobile phone because we are trying to connect that mobile phone as a GSM Modem.

Comment: Please do not put extra details in your question body. Be specific & highlight the specific terms to make it more readable.

Comment: What happened with this?